# Design with OO how to make these classes and relationships

Tags: oop, database-design

[image]

I have a Window form that will make Insert, Delete, Update the 3 DataTables as shown in above diagram and propagate changes to database tables.

with Object Oriented approach can anyone show me how these are related

PurchaseProduct Inherit from Purchase ? or association? ??

Comment: What is "PurchaseProductExp"? Are you asking for help designing the database or for help with the programming to work with the database?

Comment: one bought product can have many expires PurchaseProducExpNo is for Expire details of a product

yes asking for help designing from OOP aspects

Comment: What programming language are you wanting help with? (Databases are not object-oriented, they are normalized. Programming languages are object-oriented). Can you edit your question and provide examples of products and expire details? I'm still having trouble understanding what you're wanting...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native english speaker, so what is the meaning of `PurchaseProduktExpNo`?

Actually there should not be any inheritation in your program. It is not a "is a" but rather a "has a" relation. So you would create a list of invoices. Each invoice owns a list of boughtProducts. And each of this boughtProducts owns a list of purchesProductExpNos (whatever this is).